# Can someone's legal name be all lowercase?

Tags: name, birth-certificate, frivolous-arguments, opca

Can a person's legal name be all lowercase or all capital letters or some strange mix, or are there restrictions about it? Or maybe capitalization is not even part of the name, it is just a part of grammar for proper nouns, with traditional/linguistic exceptions for names like "McDonald" or "von Neumann"?

(This is just a curiosity question so it doesn't matter to me which countries/states the answers are based on.)

Comment: ee cummings [just how he spelt it, not necessarily really legal]

Comment: @JosephDoggie I've never had time to look into it, but I've always wondered if ee cummngs' use of all lowercase letters was simply a stylistic choice, or if there was more to it (birth certificate, name change, etc.).  Does anyone happen to have a quality reference to unlock that little mystery?

Comment: mandatory XKCD: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/85325/10334

Comment: @JosephDoggie this myth is persistent but [a myth nonetheless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Cummings#Name_and_capitalization): "Cummings' publishers and others have often echoed the unconventional orthography in his poetry by writing his name in lower case. Cummings himself used both the lowercase and capitalized versions, though he most often signed his name with capitals. The use of lower case for his initials was popularized in part by the title of some books, particularly in the 1960s, printing his name in lower case on the cover and spine. In the preface to E. E. Cummings: ...

Comment: @RobertColumbia "...The Growth of a Writer by Norman Friedman, critic Harry T. Moore notes Cummings "had his name put legally into lower case, and in his later books the titles and his name were always in lower case". According to Cummings' widow, however, this is incorrect. She wrote to Friedman: "You should not have allowed H. Moore to make such a stupid & childish statement about Cummings & his signature." On February 27, 1951, Cummings wrote to his French translator D. Jon Grossman that he preferred the use of upper case for the particular edition they were working on. ...

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket "...One Cummings scholar believes that on the rare occasions that Cummings signed his name in all lower case, he may have intended it as a gesture of humility, not as an indication that it was the preferred orthography for others to use. Additionally, The Chicago Manual of Style, which prescribes favoring non-standard capitalization of names in accordance with the bearer's strongly stated preference, notes "E. E. Cummings can be safely capitalized; it was one of his publishers, not he himself, who lowercased his name.""

Comment: My American birth certificate (maybe a bit unusual, as I was born abroad, on an American army base, so I always was an American citizen) showed my name in all uppercase, and a space in my last name. My parents used only the first letter capitalized, & eliminated the space. I went with what I was told is the more proper route, eliminating the space but still capitalizing both the first letter and also what was the first letter of the final piece when there was a space. The government never challenged this. My state-provided driver's license shows all capital letters (no space in the last name).

Comment: There is an academic called bell hooks but this is just her pen name, her legal name is Gloria Jean Watkins.

Comment: In England, your Birth Certificate will have the surname in ALL CAPS and the forename(s) in Sentence Case; https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a7f3cfe30700490bf99a604ff4d66433-lq - You're welcome to style yourself in other ways and even get a passport with weird capitalisation, but the state will always treat your name as a string of letters, regardless of how you present them.

Comment: There is some question as to whether capitalization is truly part of your name or not.

Comment: Is ☥ upper or lower case?

Comment: Relevant https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ (see 12, 13)

Comment: Some English people would be most upset if it wasn't possible. It's a snobby thing to have a surname that starts "ff" rather than F". For much more, https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2017/08/ff-names.html

Comment: I know a lady who is married to a guy named Mark. I asked her about an exam and she said “I’m happy, I got a good mark”. Then I asked about her marriage and she said “I’m happy, I got a good Mark”.

Answer (score 71):

> Or maybe capitalization is not even part of the name

That's pretty much it.  No court would fail to recognize the name "John Doe" in the string "JOHN DOE"; similarly, if someone established or claimed to establish their legal name as "john doe" then the only violations committed by someone writing it as "John Doe" or "JOHN DOE" would be violations of style, perhaps, or of etiquette.

Now, just in case this is related to the crackpot conspiracy theorists from the "sovereign citizen" or "freeman on the land" movements, a few words are in order.  If you don't already know about this, you might find it interesting.  In general, this is a school of thought that attempts to establish the illegitimacy of government authority by employing a number of illogical and willful misinterpretations of (often obsolete, foreign, or otherwise irrelevant) legal texts.  Among these is the idea that the capitalization of a name is significant.

From Wikipedia's [article on the sovereign citizen movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_citizen_movement):

> In a criminal case in 2013, the United States District Court for the Western District of Washington noted:
>
> > Defendant [Kenneth Wayne Leaming] is apparently a member of a group loosely styled "sovereign citizens". The Court has deduced this from a number of Defendant's peculiar habits.
> >
> > First, like Mr. Leaming, sovereign citizens are fascinated by capitalization. They appear to believe that capitalizing names have some sort of legal effect. For example, Defendant writes that "the REGISTERED FACTS appearing in the above Paragraph evidence the uncontroverted and uncontrovertible FACTS that the SLAVERY SYSTEMS operated in the names UNITED STATES, United States, UNITED STATES OF AMERICA, and United States of America ... are terminated nunc pro tunc by public policy, U.C.C. 1-103 ..." (Def.'s Mandatory Jud. Not. at 2.) He appears to believe that by capitalizing "United States", he is referring to a different entity than the federal government. For better or for worse, it's the same country.

From its [article on strawman theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawman_theory):

> One argument used by proponents of the strawman theory is based on a misinterpretation of the term capitis deminutio, used in ancient Roman law for the extinguishment of a person's former legal capacity. Adherents to the theory spell the term "Capitis Diminutio", and claim that capitis diminutio maxima (meaning, in Roman law, the loss of liberty, citizenship, and family) was represented by an individual's name being written in capital letters, hence the idea of individuals having a separate legal personality.
>
> Proponents of the theory believe the evidence is found on the birth certificate itself. Because many certificates show all capitals to spell out a baby's name, JOHN DOE (under the Strawman theory) is the name of the "straw man", and John Doe is the baby's "real" name. As the child grows, most legal documents will contain capital letters, which means that his state-issued driver's license, his marriage license, his car registration, his criminal court records, his cable TV bill, correspondence from the IRS, etc., pertain to his strawman and not his sovereign identity.

(Note that there was no distinction between majuscule and minuscule letters in the Latin alphabet in ancient Roman times; this distinction [arose in the 8th century](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/332/6736), a few hundred years after the fall of the western empire.)

And finally, from  [Meads v. Meads, 2012 ABQB 571 (CanLII)](https://www.canlii.org/en/ab/abqb/doc/2012/2012abqb571/2012abqb571.html):

> [323] Given the obsessive focus of the OPCA movement for documentary and procedural formalities (real or imagined), it is unsurprising that they have developed a wealth of arbitrary name-related rules. For example, Canadian courts have evaluated and rejected the following nomenclature-related schemes:
>
> - a person is not immune from court action if that person identifies himself by an entirely different name, for example, “Mythlim‑Axkw” instead of “Kazimierz Chester Crischuk”: R. v. Crischuk, 2010 BCSC 716 at paras. 31-32, affirmed 2010 BCCA 391, 2010 D.T.C. 5141; Shakes v. Canada (Public Safety and Emergency Preparedness), 2011 CanLII 60494 at para. 11 (I.R.B.); Services de financement TD inc. c. Michaud, 2011 QCCQ 14868 at para. 6;
> - structuring a name in the format of [Firstname]-[Middlename]: [Lastname], i.e. “David-Kevin: Lindsay”, does not mean one is a separate person from “David Kevin Lindsay”: R. v. Lindsay, 2006 BCCA 150 at para. 3, 265 D.L.R. (4th) 193; R. v. Lindsay, 2008 BCPC 203 at para. 7, [2009] 1 C.T.C 86, affirmed 2010 BCSC 831, [2010] 5 C.T.C. 174, affirmed 2011 BCCA 99, 302 B.C.A.C. 76, leave refused [2011] S.C.C.A. No. 265;
> - structuring a name in the format [Firstname] of the [family] of [Lastname], i.e. “John Donald of the family Sargent”, does not mean one is a separate person from “John Donald Sargent”: R. v. Sargent, 2004 ONCJ 356 at para. 29, [2005] 1 C.T.C. 448;
> - there is no legal distinction between a name in upper case and lower case letters, and a name all in capital letters: R. v. Linehan, 2000 ABQB 815 at para. 13, 276 A.R. 383; R. v. Loosdrecht, 2008 BCPC 400 at para. 36, [2009] 4 C.T.C. 49; R. v. Lemieux, 2007 SKPC 135 at paras. 45-46, [2008] 2 C.T.C. 291;
> - a claim that the person named in litigation is incorrectly identified by a “war name” or “nom de guerre” is irrelevant: Canada v. Galbraith, 2001 BCSC 675 at paras. 25-29, 54 W.C.B. (2d) 504; and
> - a name all in capitals is not a “legal fiction” and not different from “a flesh, blood and bone man”: Ontario (Director, Family Responsibility Office) v. Boyle, [2006] O.J. No. 2181 (QL) at paras. 3-5, 149 A.C.W.S. (3d) 127 (Ont. Sup. Ct. J.).

Comment: 50 years ago, a name had no legal significance at all: you could call yourself whatever you wanted and have as many names as you wanted. Your driver's license, bank account and passport could all be in different names. In the USA there has gradually developed the idea of "real name", culminating in the introduction of "REAL ID".

Comment: Now that's a very interesting thing. In Germany, there are people which claim that the FRG doesn't exist as a country, that the Empire still exists (but still occupied by the Allies) and that the FRG ist just a company whose emploees we are (BRD GmbH, something like FRG Ltd. or FRG Inc.). Somewhere along these lines, they start talking about having our names in the ID also means that we are not free, but slaves of (whatever/whomever). Now it is very intersting to see that this kind of people also exist in other countries.

Comment: As a programmer I must argue with the claim no court would fail to recognize a name due to capitalization.  Sure legally there is no different, but I guarantee the courts also use computers and having seen the average programming skill of developers I'm sure there have been plenty of courts who had problems due to their software not recognizing names due to capitalization.  Never underestimate the potential incompetence of humans! :P ;)

Comment: Or worse - capitalization in other cultures.  Once you get out of the ASCII range (and even somewhat inside it) there's all sorts of fun that follows...

Comment: Notably, people speaking legalese also often [think that capitalization makes words more important](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/743/do-disclaimers-need-to-be-capitalized)

Comment: Capitalization *can* matter in some cases, for example to refer to words that have some special definition. But unless the document defines the capitalized word (or references another document that does), the word means what it normally means.

Comment: @cHao that's also more a matter of style than of legal effect.  For example, if a petition says 'John Doe, hereinafter referred to as "Petitioner,"' and then subsequently fails to capitalize 'petitioner' somewhere, that doesn't deprive the word of its function as a reference to John Doe.

Comment: @david the capacity to use multiple names does not mean that names have or had no legal significance.

Comment: @dsollen I am of course speaking of the judicial interpretation of a text, not of a database lookup.  I agree wholeheartedly that there could be a database system whereby searches that should find people don't, whether because of different capitalization or simply because of alternate spelling.  I've been working on such a system in my day job, where objects belonging to Cindy Peterson are returned from a search for those belonging to Cindy Peters because there is a substring search for the person's name.  Ugh.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen notably, among those people have been some judges in the US, which is why the practice is so common in the US.

Comment: @phoog I don't know about legal status of 'real name' in other countries. In the countries I am familiar with, there was no concept of 'real name' or 'legal name', and the names you called yourself, or others called you, including in court or on legal documents, had no intrinsic legal significance. REAL ID changes this, because you must maintain a continuous chain of legally documented name changes.

Comment: @david ... If you want to be able to use your driver's license to board a flight in the US, that is.  Real ID doesn't prevent you from adopting a new name under the common law in states that permit it, and many states allow you to continue to have a non-Real-ID license.  Real ID just makes it more inconvenient to do so.  Much of western Europe in my experience does have a rather firmer concept of legal name.  I've often had to use my cumbersome middle name, which I usually omit, because it's listed in my passport.

Answer (score 22):

This depends on jurisdiction and the general answer is yes/no/both/either/it depends.

See this well-known essay about what is or isn't true about names in general: [*Falsehoods Programmers Believe about Names*](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) by Patrick McKenzie (and a number of other renditions of the same name...)

In *very* brief, it is not universally true that all persons have a name, or a single name, or a single canonical name, or a small set of canonical names (let alone unique, or adhering to any particular orthographic convention, or fixed over time).

Comment: "yes/no/both/either/it depends": well said, but to the extent that a name is used for identifying someone, failure to use the "correct" case or even the correct spelling isn't usually decisive.

Comment: Ahhh, I was about to post about the falsehoods - you were faster :) Very good read.

Comment: I was about to post that link myself, but I see you already did it. Should be mandatory reading for anyone having to deal with naming conventions (not just programmers). By the way... Most of it applies to placenames/addresses as well. Anyone who has to deal with cross-border logistics/international shipping systems can testify to that.

Comment: The first part of this provides minimal information and no evidence for it; the second part is related but doesn't answer the question, so it would be better as a [comment (available starting at 50 reputation)](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on the question.

Comment: @SolomonUcko the second part very much _does_ answer the question, and pretty conclusively: a person's name can be _anything_, even considering legal restrictions. It should be mandatory reading for any social context involving names.

Comment: It appears this is essentially a "link-only answer."

Comment: I submitted an edit suggestion to hopefully summarize the linked article adequately.

Comment: What is true about a person's legal name obviously depends on the jurisdiction. Some countries do not regulate this at all, i.e. the term is not well-defined in some jurisdictions.

Answer (score 15):

### Lowercase names are impossible in [japan](/questions/tagged/japan), [prc](/questions/tagged/prc), [rc](/questions/tagged/rc), [rok](/questions/tagged/rok), [dprk](/questions/tagged/dprk)

Any name that is on a Japanese identity document (the "my Number" card/ID card) or in the official citizen register is written in Hiragana, Katakana or Kanji. None of these scripts support capitalization. Latin letters ("Romanji") do not appear on documents that are not international passports - where they only appear as a transliteration of the Japanese document entry. An exception to the no latin characters on internal documents are *Residency cards* for foreigners that do not have Japanese Citizenship, their cards contain the subject name, all in monospace capital letters. However, naturalization requires choosing a name that is written in Hiragana, Katakana, or Kanji (there's a list which are allowable).

Similarly, the Chinese script does not support capitalization either, nor does Hangul. In both Chinas and Koreas, you need the name to be in the respective script as a citizen.

As a result, Japan, the People's Republic of China, the Republic of China, The Republic of Korea, and the Democratic People's Republic of Korea all don't support a name in lowercase. Or uppercase for the matter, because all the letters are same sized.

### You have misconceptions about names? Here are some more that don't work on Asian Passports!

Oh, and for the matter:  the 5 are just the tip of the iceberg, and don't conform to the following [*programmer misconceptions*](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) on names...

> 9. People’s names are written in ASCII. [ASCII is only Latin letters]
> 10. People’s names are written in any single character set. [Japanese names can legally use all three!]

> 12. People’s names are case sensitive.
> 13. People’s names are case insensitive. [There is no case in those languages]

> 16. People’s names are not written in ALL CAPS.
> 17. People’s names are not written in all lower case letters. [Uh, there's no case?]
> 18. People’s names have an order to them.  Picking any ordering scheme will automatically result in consistent ordering among all systems, as long as both use the same ordering scheme for the same name. [So not true! If you transliterate to Latin characters, you also swap family names and given names around or not, depending on who is the recipient!]

> 30. There exists an algorithm which transforms names and can be reversed losslessly.  (Yes, yes, you can do it if your algorithm returns the input.  You get a gold star.) [Try that with the [almost 400 different names that contain Riku](https://jisho.org/search/riku%20%23names) in Japanese, of which only few are duplicative, and all have different connotations and meanings]

Comment: Scripts that support capitalization (known as "bicameral scripts" are the exception rather than the rule.  There are many other countries aside from those mentioned in this answer whose whose national languages don't do this.

Comment: @phoog just that those 5 legally don't allow a name on their identity document that is in Latin script.

Comment: @phoog: I'm accustomed to "change case" operations being just fine on languages that don't have cases. It's the few languages where the mapping isn't one to one that cause problems.

Comment: @Trish how can you not allow names on documents that are in Latin script?  Surely you don't mean that documents in Latin script can't have names on them.  Do you mean that they don't allow names in Latin scripts on the documents when the documents aren't otherwise in a Latin script?  Or do you mean that they print Latin names in one case only (which seems to be the case with the pictures of Japanese ID cards that I've found online)?

Comment: @phoog An citizen's ID document for Japan from Japan does not contain a single character from Latin script in the field entries. Numbers are not latin characters anyway, they are Indian numerals. The law simply doesn't allow for the name field to contain Latin characters for citizens, while foreigner residency cards (which are *separate*) *can* and do contain Latin script, but only in the name field and on the labels. Acquiring citizenship requires choosing a name that can be written in one of the allowable characters.

Comment: @phoog in contrary, the new digital japanese ID-Card ("My Number") has as far as I can tell no latin characters on it at all, it is for domestic use only. PAssports *do* contain a Romanji-writing of names, to allow processing of the names in *other* countries, but japan processes them under the *proper* registered name in Japanese scripts.

Comment: English is the international standard. All those writing systems can be romanised and stored in ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I see now that the cards I was looking at are residence permits, consistent with your explanation.

Comment: @nick012000 The most common romanization in the world, pinyin, easily becomes ambiguous if you don't allow diacritics/numbers and occasionally an apostrophe. Because these aren't supported in the ICAO format, the romanization on a PRC passport is one-way. The HKSAR official Cantonese romanization is ambiguous to begin with, on top of that it can be overridden because individuals and families may have utilized different romanizations.

Answer (score 7):

In the U.S., names are generally left to the choice of parents and the person who bears the name, though as a convention of common languages spoken in the U.S., the name is likely to be given capital letters where appropriate. On some standardized forms, (I believe the SATs did this) names would be filled out in a field that was two rows with each column for one letter. The first row would have all the capital letters while the second row would use all lowercase letters. Leaving a column blank would indicate a space. So someone named McDonald would have the M and first instance of D in the upper column and all other letters in the lower column.

Other nations that are more controlling on legitimate names (not uncommon in nations with nearly homogenous ethnicities like Sweden) it's likely that the name will be properly capitalized in its acceptable spelling variants.

Usually, the signature is not about identity but acknowledging the document was accepted by leaving a unique mark on the document.  Forgery detection relies on consistent characteristics of the signature (like how Walt Disney used the tail of the "y" in his name to underline the full signature) to determine authenticity.  Someone who would always sign with all lower case letters is still valid because it creates a unique identity to the signature that a forger might not know (and it is impossible to make the same signature twice, so if the signer was not known to use an autopen, the signature may look too similar to be real.).

Comment: *not uncommon in nations with nearly homogenous ethnicities like Sweden* — Sweden does not have a nearly homogenous ethnicity (anymore).  There are many people with parents or grandparents born abroad and there are [five recognised national minorities](https://sweden.se/life/equality/swedens-national-minorities).

Comment: Iceland would be a much better example than Sweden — more ethnically homogeneous, and a much more restrictive name policy.

Comment: "D in the upper column and all other letters in the lower column" - should "column" be "row" in those two instances?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine To illustrate: Iceland only allows you to name your kid with a name that is deemed *icelandic*